# Unable to start a Wasp test chain on WSL

Tags: iota-network, iota-cli

While trying to deploy a wasp chain I am receiving the following timeout error:

```
wasp-cli chain deploy --committee=0 --quorum=1 --ch
ain=mychain --description="My chain"
creating new chain. Owner address: 1BsTvwN9jqFnF2t8....MbF3J1hza7. State controller: KsKvhbyBhHJQw....5uFcT51mLSsmBu8h, N = 1, T = 1
creating chain origin and init transaction 4GCMCGzzwUdzEVd1X1WB....GZYBwADUssw.. OK
sending committee record to nodes.. OK
activating chain ia4oztPgHCQJKyAy2zvVGsoFGQAyoxUhrrVCc6urEBGU.. FAILED: ActivateChainOnAccessNodes: #0: MultiCall: timeout
```

I have followed both [wiki](https://wiki.iota.org/smart-contracts/guide/chains_and_nodes/setting-up-a-chain) and the [video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mLpV_neB6I&list=PLMbc46iGTB_SCQ-Ut_c8__ssMDFUusVBJ) but still facing the same issue.

I am running only 1 wasp node on WSL and receiving the following nodeconn warning:

```
2021-12-17T14:35:03+05:30       WARN    NodeConn        client/connection.go:56     can't connect with the server: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused
```

I am super new here and don't know how to resolve this error. Any help will be appreciated, please.

My environment setup:

1. Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu-20.04)
2. Go 1.16.4
3. wasp-cli.json

```
{
  "wallet": {
    "seed": "<<seed-value>>"
  },
  "goshimmer": {
    "api": "shimmer.chrysalis2.com:8080",
    "faucetpowtarget": -1
  },
  "wasp": {
    "0": {
      "api": "127.0.0.1:9090",
      "nanomsg": "127.0.0.1:5550",
      "peering": "127.0.0.1:4000"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the goshimmer api as per the [testnet endpoints](https://wiki.iota.org/smart-contracts/guide/chains_and_nodes/testnet#endpoints), which should be `https://api.goshimmer.sc.iota.org/`.

Also, for now, you can use `"faucetpowtarget": 21` instead.

Alternatively, if you can, setup everything locally for now. The testnet is highly experimental right now and might be down for upgrades or tests quite often.